# Why posting to PayPal sandbox API not working for me?

Tags: rest, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I POST (with suitable `Authorization:` header) to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`

```
{"intent": "sale", "payer": {"payment_method": "paypal"}, "transactions": [{"amount": 10.0, "currency": "USD", "details": {"subtotal": 10.0, "shipping": 0.0, "tax": 0.0}, "description": "Item 1"}], "redirect_urls": {"return_url": "https://example.com", "cancel_url": "https://example.com"}}
```

and receive in return

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"815ed32bcd78e"}
```

Why the error? What is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the paypal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create)

See the example on the right side. `amount` should be an object - `currency` and `details` need to be attributes of `amount`, also you are missing the required `total` attribute

Reworked JSON

```
{
   "intent":"sale",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"paypal"
   },
   "transactions":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "total":"10.00",
            "currency":"USD",
            "details":{
               "subtotal":"10.00",
               "shipping":"0.00",
               "tax":"0.00"
            }
         },
         "description":"Item 1"
      }
   ],
   "redirect_urls":{
      "return_url":"https://example.com",
      "cancel_url":"https://example.com"
   }
}
```

Please be careful when specifying "price-numbers" (total, subtotal, ...) they must be strings and follow rules about decimal digits

Answer (score 0):

### **The question was edited and this answer is no longer relevant.**

Comment: The JSON was with double quotes. I presented my question incorrectly. I edited the question. Please remove your answer, as it answers a wrong previous version of the question